# Extract DNA from FASTA with regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a set of DNA sequences as below

```
>gi|58445847s cyclin-dependent kinase inhibitor 1B (p27, Kip1) (CDKN1B), mRNA
ATGTCAAACGTGCGAGTGTCTAACGGGAGCCCTAGCCTGGAGCGGATGGACGCCAGGCAGGCGGAGCACC
GCCCAAGAAGCCTGGCCTCAGAAGACGTCAAACGTAA

>gi|584458479:571-1167 Homo sapiens 1B (p27, Kip1) (CDKN1B), mRNA
ATGTCAAACGTGCGAGTGTCTAACGGGAGCCCTAGCCTGGAGCGGATGGACGCCAGGCAGGCGGAGCACC
ACAAAAGAGCCAACAGAACAGAAGAAAATGTTTCAGACGGTTCCCCAAATGCCGGTTCTGTGGAGCAGAC
GCCCAAGAAGCCTGGCCTCAGAAGACGTCAAACGTAA
```

I want to extract only the `[ATGC]+` and the line starting with `>` should be ignored.

This is the regex I have made.

```
(?!\>.*\n)[ATGC\n]+
```

But first group it finds is `C` in `(CDKN1B)` then starts from A in `, mRNA` to line before next `>`

**Update**
Following Java code can be used to find DNA sequences from file. Use `findWithinHorizon(pattern, 0)` instead of `useDelimiter(patter)`.

```
List<String> sequences = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fc.getSelectedFile())));
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[ACTG]+(?:\\r\\n[ACTG]+)*", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    String str = s.findWithinHorizon(p, 0);
    do {
        sequences.add(str);
        str = s.findWithinHorizon(p, 0);
    } while (str != null);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
} finally {
    if (s != null) {
        s.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an anchor for the start of the line and the multiline modifier:

```
(?m)^[ACTG\n]+
```

The lookahead is useless.

or if you want to trim the last newline character:

```
(?m)^[ACTG]+(?:\n[ACTG]+)*
```

An example that use java.util.scanner:

```
String input = ">gi|58445847s cyclin-dependent kinase inhibitor 1B (p27, Kip1) (CDKN1B), mRNA\n"
             + "ATGTCAAACGTGCGAGTGTCTAACGGGAGCCCTAGCCTGGAGCGGATGGACGCCAGGCAGGCGGAGCACC\n"
             + "GCCCAAGAAGCCTGGCCTCAGAAGACGTCAAACGTAA\n"
             + "\n"
             + ">gi|584458479:571-1167 Homo sapiens 1B (p27, Kip1) (CDKN1B), mRNA\n"
             + "ATGTCAAACGTGCGAGTGTCTAACGGGAGCCCTAGCCTGGAGCGGATGGACGCCAGGCAGGCGGAGCACC\n"                   
             + "ACAAAAGAGCCAACAGAACAGAAGAAAATGTTTCAGACGGTTCCCCAAATGCCGGTTCTGTGGAGCAGAC\n"
             + "GCCCAAGAAGCCTGGCCTCAGAAGACGTCAAACGTAA\n";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[ACTG]+(?:\\n[ACTG]+)*$", Pattern.MULTILINE);

Scanner s = new Scanner(input);
s.useDelimiter("\n");   

while(s.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(s.findWithinHorizon(p, 0) + "\n");
}
```

Comment: That fitted effortlessly in java.

Comment: It does not give correct output with `Scanner.useDelimiter`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `^` at the start. So that it would check that the whole line matches the condition given in the assertion or not.

```
^(?!>.*\n)[ATGC\n]+
```

OR

```
^(?!>.*\n)[ATGC]+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uS5qR5/4)

Comment: Your regex needs a multiline flag.

Comment: did you forget adding that ? Add multiline modifier whenever anchors are used in your regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
^>.*?\n|([ATGC\n]+)
```

simply try this and grab the group 1 .See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eS7gD7/31

Comment: Works fine. Only catch is even group numbers.

Comment: @LifeH2O `group 1` ,`group 2` etc will be your answers not even ones